# Xcode jump from viewcontroller.swift to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm working on a large ios app and I'm also a newb. I'm trying to find the correct scene in a storyboard in a large app. I'm in the .swift file and I need a quick way to figure out which scene is associated with that swift controller file. The only way I know now is to go through each scene and look at the Class property, which will take forever. Is there a shortcut to jump from the swift file to the associated scene?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

1. In Xcode, open "*Find in Workspace...*" (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. Type the name of your ViewController.
3. In the results panel, check the entries under the *.storyboard* file. Clicking on them will open that exactly scene in the Interface Builder.
4. Profit.

---

You can also go further and filter the search by **filetype**. Check this out:

Create a custom Scope:

[image]

Super awesome result:

[image: Custom scope FTW]

Comment: Another way: Put the cursor in the class name "LoginController" or highlight it, then do Find -> **Find Selected Text In Project**